# Simplify Rational Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I got this question on my math homework.

$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{3}}{4\sqrt{3}+4\sqrt{2}}
$$

The instructions are to simplify and rationalize the denominator. 
I've been trying to get the correct answer for a while now, but the answers I get never look right.
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What methods have you tried so far?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I've tried multiplying the bottom terms by the top and foiling them.

Comment: What can you multiply the bottom by to get a difference of squares?

Comment: I suggest you put the terms in the same order top and bottom.  i.e. $\frac {2\sqrt 2 - 2\sqrt 3}{4\sqrt 2 + 4\sqrt 3}$ it doesn't change anything, but it makes it easier to keep organized as you simplify.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{3}}{4\sqrt{3}+4\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})}{4(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{2(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})\cdot (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}{2(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) \cdot (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}$$
$$=\frac{2\sqrt{6}-5}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**:

- Divide numerator and denominator by $2$;
- When one has a fraction with $\sqrt{a} \pm \sqrt{b}$ in the denominator, it helps if you multiply both numerator and denominator of the fraction by the conjugate of the denominator, $\sqrt{a} \mp \sqrt{b}$. That is, if the denominator is $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ multiply by $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ and if the denominator is $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ then multiply by $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$

Comment: $(a- b)(a+b)= a^2- b^2$

Comment: @user247327 Indeed, that is the motivation;

Comment: +1 for full answer that is well responded to homework questions.

Comment: @SimpleArt thanks, but what do you mean?

Comment: I like good answers that provide *how* to solve the problem without actually solving it in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

When asked to rationalize the denominator, you need to multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator. A conjugate is a binomial with the sign switched from positive to negative or negative to positive. So, the conjugate of your denominator, $$4\sqrt{3}+4\sqrt{2}$$ is $$4\sqrt{3}-4\sqrt{2}$$
Since you are going to multiply the numerator and denominator by the same number, then you are not changing the value of the fraction. 
$$\frac{2\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{3}}{4\sqrt{3}+4\sqrt{2}}\times\frac{4\sqrt{3}-4\sqrt{2}}{4\sqrt{3}-4\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{8\sqrt{6}-8\sqrt{4}-8\sqrt{9}+8\sqrt{6}}{16\sqrt{9}-16\sqrt{6}+16\sqrt{6}-16\sqrt{4}}$$
$$=\frac{16\sqrt{6}-8\times 2-8 \times 3}{16\times 3-16\times 2}$$
$$=\frac{16\sqrt{6}-40}{16}$$
$$=\frac{2\sqrt{6}-5}{2}$$